# Proper way to end meeting for all participants in Skype for Business using Lync SDK

Tags: c#, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I’m trying to implement a function for ending the current conversation for all participants using Microsoft Lync SDK for Skype for business. The job it’s supposed to be done like this:

```
conversation.End();
```

But it only closes the window of the participant that started the meeting.
Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The "End" method just leave the conference call as you say.

There is no documented API to "End Meeting".

If you really want to do this programmatically then you will need to use something like [Windows Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal) to select the "More options" button then then select the "End Meeting" button.

Here is a example method for using windows automation to click the End Meeting button.

```
bool EndMeeting(ConversationWindow window)
{
    var conversationWindowElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(window.InnerObject.Handle);
    if (conversationWindowElement == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    AutomationElement moreOptionsMenuItem;
    if (GetAutomationElement(conversationWindowElement, out moreOptionsMenuItem, "More options", ControlType.MenuItem))
    {
        (moreOptionsMenuItem.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern) as ExpandCollapsePattern).Expand();
    }
    else if (GetAutomationElement(conversationWindowElement, out moreOptionsMenuItem, "More options", ControlType.Button))
    {
        // in the Office 365 version of lync client, the more options menu item is actually a button
        (moreOptionsMenuItem.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern).Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        // didn't find it.
        return false;
    }

    AutomationElement menuOptionAction;
    if (!GetAutomationElement(moreOptionsMenuItem, out menuOptionAction, "End Meeting", ControlType.MenuItem))
    {
        return false;
    }

    (menuOptionAction.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern).Invoke();
    return true;
}

private static bool GetAutomationElement(AutomationElement rootElement, out AutomationElement resultElement, string name, ControlType expectedControlType)
{
    Condition propCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, name, PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);
    resultElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, propCondition);
    if (resultElement == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var controlTypeId = resultElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty) as ControlType;
    if (!Equals(controlTypeId, expectedControlType))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```